# traveling salesman problem dynamic programming

Tags: c++, recursion, traveling-salesman

I've written a code, that gives the least cost for an array, which stores length of paths from each city to each city. I used recursion in my code. User chooses the first city from which the salesman begins his tour. The salesman has to visit each city once and come back to city which he started from. My code gives the correct  cost, but I have no idea how to get the path, which gives that least cost. Should I use some extra arrays? I don't know when to add a city to the path. Any help?

```
void Dynamic::dynamic(Array array)
{
    int start;
    size = array.getSize();
    s = size;
    path = new int[size+1];
    
    
    
    cout << "Which city we start from?" << endl;
    cin >> start;
    int* cities = new int[size];
    for (int i=0; i<size+1; i++)
    {
        cities[i] = i;
        
    }
    
    
    
    int cost = g(array, size-1, cities, start, start, s);
    
    cout<<"Minimum cost: " << cost << endl;
    cout << "Path:" <<endl;
    
    for (int i=size; i>=0; i--)
    {
        cout << path[i] << "\t";
    }
    
    cout << "\n";
    
}

int Dynamic::g(Array & array, int level, int* tab, int city, int start, int z)
{
    if (level>0)
    {
        

        int minimum = INF;
        
        
        int position;
        bool exists = false;
        int k = z;
    
        for (int i=0; i<z; i++)
        {
            
            if (tab[i] == city)
            {
                position = i;
                exists = true;
            }
        }
        
        int* tmp;
        
    if (exists == true)
    
    {
        k = z-1;
        tmp = new int [k];
        for (int i=0; i<position; i++)
        {
            tmp[i] = tab[i];
        }
    
        for (int i=position; i<k; i++)
        {
            tmp[i] = tab[i+1];
        }
    }
    
    else
    {
        tmp = new int [k];
        for (int i=0; i<k; i++)
        {
            tmp[i] = tab[i];
        }
    }
    
        
        for (int i=0; i<k; i++)
        {
        
        
            
            int c = array[city][tmp[i]];
        
            int* t = new int [k-1];
            for(int j=0; j<i; j++)
            {
                t[j] = tmp[j];
            }           
            
            for (int j=i; j<k-1; j++)
            {
                t[j] = tmp[j+1];
            }
        
            
            int a = g(array, level-1, t, tmp[i], start, k-1);
            
            int result = c + a;
            
            if (minimum> result)
            {
                minimum = result;
                
                
                
            }
            
            
        }
        
        return minimum;
    }
    
    if (level == 0)
    {
        
        return array[city][start];
    }
}
```

Comment: The loop `for (int i=0; i<size+1; i++)` will go out of bounds for `cities` and lead to *undefined behavior*. And why are you using your own explicit memory handling instead of `std::vector`? Especially considering that you don't free the memory you allocate.

Comment: And what is `Array`? Have you created your own `std::vector` alternative? Why? And why do you pass it by value to your `dynamic` function?

Comment: class array just reads a .txt file, which stores paths from each city to each city

Comment: first line is the number of cities, and in next lines i have costs to other cities. Array is like [number_of_cities][number_of_cities] cost from a city to the same city is 0. But my code avoids risk of going to the same city again.

Comment: @czesiek You've written code that leaks memory all over the place.  Use `std::vector`, not `new[]` and `delete[]`.

Comment: But when should I add the city to the path? I think I still don't understand the recursion properly.